# Why is there tearing on my desktop when OC'ing video card?

Tags: troubleshooting, aero, amd-radeon, overclocking

I've got a brand new Radeon 5750 in my system.  It works great at stock clocks, and performs even better when overclocked.  I have been using the ATI Overdrive facility build into the Catalyst drivers to do this.  The problem is, whenever I have Overdrive enabled, there is significant tearing on my desktop whenever I move or resize a window.  I thought this was caused by the card missing the vsync window when redrawing, but I'm starting to think its something more.

I've tried setting my LCD's to both 60 and 75 Hz refresh, the only 2 resolutions they support.  What is really confusing though, is that this happens no matter what clock speeds I pick, as long as Overdrive is on.  Even if I select the stock speeds, or underclock the card, this happens.  Turning overdrive off resolves this problem.

Drivers are up to date from ATI, Win 7 Pro 64 with Aero enabled.  Gigabyte MA785GMT-UD2H mainboard, with the integrated HD4200 disabled.  PCI-E is set in BIOS as the primary display adapter.

What is causing this?  How (besides turning off Overdrive) do I prevent this artifacting?

Comment: YOU: Doctor! doctor! it hurts when I do *this*. DOCTOR: Well, *don't do it!*

Comment: Have you enabled Vsync ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are running your card above specifications and having problems!  The resolution is easy.

Comment: But he says it still does not work at stock speeds, so it's something more.

Comment: Overdrive overclocks the card.

Comment: You can also just turn it on without overclocking, or *underclock* it, which he has done.

Comment: As Blorgbeard has said, I get these issues simply by turning overdrive on.  I can set to the stock clock speeds and its still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner&menu=8) instead of Overdrive, although beware it's not for newbies.